# Gnome 3 on 12.10 notification panel disables bottom of screen

Tags: 12.10, gnome, panel

I can't cilck on anything in the bottom 2cm of my screen, which I think is due to the Gnome notification panel - how can I disable this or stop it deactivating my screen?

Answer (score 0):

Not certain if this is the answer you desire - ALT - Right Click on the bottom panel